# Testing React hook from and yup validation using jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, yup

I am trying to test this form component(I have used react-bootstrap for UI).

```
const validationSchema = 
     Yup.object().shape({
        username: Yup.string().required(),
        password: Yup.string().required(),
      })

const formOptions = { resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema) };

  // get functions to build form with useForm() hook
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, formState } = useForm(formOptions);
  const { errors } = formState;

 function onSubmit(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
return (
      <div
        data-test="reg-login-component"
        className="bg-dark pt-4"
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <Card style={{ width: "50vw", margin: "auto" }}>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>Login</Card.Title>
            <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
           
              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col} md="12" sm="12" xs="12">
                  <Form.Label>UserName</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    name="username"
                    type="text"
                    {...register("username")}
                  />
                  <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-danger mt-0">
                    {" "}
                    {errors.username?.message}
                  </Card.Subtitle>
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
              <Container fluid className="pr-0 pl-0">
                <Form.Row>
                  <Form.Group as={Col}>
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                      name="password"
                      type="password"
                      {...register("password")}
                    />
                    <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-danger mt-0">
                      {" "}
                      {errors.password?.message}
                    </Card.Subtitle>
                  </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>
              </Container>
              <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
)};

Registration.test.js


Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });

const setup = ()=> {
  return mount(<Registration  />);
};

describe("Checking valid inputs", () => {
  it("submits input values", async () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn();
    const handleUserData = jest.fn();

    const rendered = setup();

  
    await act(async () => {
      rendered
        .find('input[name="username"]')
        .simulate("input", { value: "harshitsankhala" })
        .simulate("blur");
    });
   
  
    await act(async () => {
      rendered.find("form").simulate("submit");
    });

    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        username: "harshitsankhala",
      })
    );
  });
});
```

when running npm test
getting this error ->

```
   Checking valid inputs
    × submits input values (81 ms)

  ● Checking valid inputs › submits input values

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: ObjectContaining {"username": "harshitsankhala"}

    Number of calls: 0

      58 |     });
      59 |
    > 60 |     expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(
         |                      ^
      61 |       expect.objectContaining({
      62 |         username: "harshitsankhala",
      63 |       })
```

i have used this code as a refrence for testing ->https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-enzyme-testing-example-5tn7i?from-embed=&file=/src/**tests**/app.test.js

How to resolve this issue??
or
How to perform test for react-hook-form and yup validation using enzyme and jest

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jest:

```
const name = await mySchema.isValid({name: 'test'});
expect(desc).toEqual(false);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77367024/6170191